# How to write exceptions traceback to a file using python

Tags: python, exception

Currently, my code gives traceback exception in console as per my expectations. I want to write exceptions to a file but code is not writing any exceptions to the file. A file is created but it is blank.

```
except Exception as error:
    print(traceback.print_exc())
    f = open('ErrorFile.txt', 'w')
    f.write(traceback.print_exc())
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_exc()` does not return the traceback as a string. Instead it `print`s it directly. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc):

> `traceback.print_exc([limit[, file]])`
>
> This is a shorthand for `print_exception(sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value, sys.exc_traceback, limit, file)`. (In fact, it uses `sys.exc_info()` to retrieve the same information in a thread-safe way instead of using the deprecated variables.)

Therefore you should use:

```
traceback.print_exc(file=f)
```